# Compare permutations of a string with words stored in a text file

Tags: c++, stl

I intend to find out if any permutation(s) of a user inputted string is a valid word in a text file with few words.

After inputting string, nothing happens! What's wrong with "if" stmt or what? Also, if I write an else that is executed which means control never reached to if even though I input words present in the list.txt

What can I try to fix this?

```
//check if any permutation of a user inputted word are in a pre defined text file

    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <vector>

    using namespace std;

    int main(){
        cout<<"Enter a word to check for the presence of any
        << of its permutation in a file \n"; 
        string word; 
        cin>>word; 
        sort(word.begin(), word.end()); 
        vector<string> str; 
        do str.push_back(word);
        while( next_permutation(word.begin(),word.end()) );                  

        ifstream readFile("list.txt");
        string line;
        while(readFile>>line){
              for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i){
                  if(line==str[i]){
                     cout << "found " << str[i] << endl;
                     break;
                  }
              }
        }
        system("pause");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Comment: The program is absolutely fine, i was giving input at run time in lowercase while my strings in text file are in uppercase..wasted hours, got to know blunder.. thanks all though for correcting previous flaws and inefficiencies in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You should store the strings to search in a vector.

```
vector<string> words_to_search;
sort(word.begin(), word.end()); 
do 
   words_to_search.push_back(word);
while (next_permutation(word.begin(), word.end()));
```

Then you can loop through them like this

```
for (vector<string>::iterator i = words_to_search.begin();
     i != words_to_search.end(); ++i)
{
    string search_word = *i;
    // search for search_word
    ...
}
```

2) To compare your strings just use ==

```
if (line == search)
```

You might need to remove leading and trailing white space from `line` first though.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your dictionary is exceptionally huge (so large you can't hold it all in memory), I'd read a word from the dictionary, create a copy and sort the letters in the copy, then add those to a vector of pairs of sorted/original words. When you've read them all, sort your vector in order by the sorted words.

When you want to check if the dictionary contains a (permuted) word, sort that word, then use `std::equal_range` on your vector to find all the words that match it.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to do any permutations.

You simply sort the characters of each word in your dictionary and compare to the sorted characters in the user-inputted string.  They may match more than one word.  You can store the dictionary in pairs.  I would do this once and store it for later use.  eg:

```
addpy paddy
orst sort
cet etc
```

If you then sort the dictionary pairs by the first (sorted) word, you can use a binary search to quickly find the sorted user string, then look in both directions for additional matching words.